# Equivariant cohomology vs. invariant cohomology vs. cohomology of quotient space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, group-cohomology, equivariant-cohomology

Given a space $X$ and an action of a group $G$ on $X$, the $G$-invariant cochains with coefficients in an Abelian group $A$ define a sub-cocomplex $\mathcal{C}^{\bullet}_G$ of the cocomplex $\mathcal{C}^{\bullet}$ of cochains with coefficients in $A$. I will call the cohomology $H^{\bullet}(\mathcal{C}_G)$ the "invariant cohomology" of $X$. What is the relationship between the follwing three objects: (i) the invariant cohomology, (ii) the usual equivariant cohomology $\mathcal{H}_G^{\bullet}(X, A)$, and (iii) the cohomology of the quotient space $H^{\bullet}(X/G,A)$? Note that I am most interested in the case where $A$ is a finite Abelian group.

I think that there are always homomorphisms
$$H^n(X/G,A) \to H^n(\mathcal{C}_G) \to \mathcal{H}_G^n(X,A).$$
The first map comes from pulling back the projection $X \to X/G$, and the second can be seen from the interpretation of equivariant cohomology as the total cohomology of the double cocomplex of group cochains of $G$ valued in $\mathcal{C}^{\bullet}$. 
But how does one characterize the kernel and image of these maps? Is there a simple statement if $X$ is contractible, say?

[Edit: regarding the relationship between $H^n(X/G,A)$ and $H^n(\mathcal{C}_G)$, please see the comments on Mark Grant's answer. The upshot is that with simplicial cochains, $H^n(\mathcal{C}_G)$ seems to depend on the choice of triangulation. But, if one defines $\mathcal{C}_G$ in a suitably triangulation-independent way, i.e. either singular cochains, or simplicial cochains on the abstract simplicial complex containing *all* simplex embeddings into X, then $H^n(\mathcal{C}_G)$ and $H^n(X/G,A)$ are almost certainly not the same.]

Answer (score 11):

In what follows I will assume that $G$ is discrete and that $X$ is a simplicial complex with regular $G$-action (see Bredon's "Introduction to compact transformation groups", Chapter III.1). The regularity condition can be ensured by passing to the second barycentric subdivision if necessary. Under these conditions (unless I have overlooked something), the invariant cochains on $X$ are the same thing as cochains on the orbit space $X/G$.

A $k$-cochain on $X/G$ is a function $\phi$ from the $k$-simplices of $X/G$ to $A$. Let $\pi:X\to X/G$ denote the orbit projection. Then $\pi^*\phi$, which assigns to a simplex $\sigma\subseteq X$ the value $\phi(\pi(\sigma))$, is an invariant $k$-cochain on $X$. (That $\pi(\sigma)$ is a simplex of $X/G$ is ensured by regularity.)

Conversely, given an invariant $k$-cochain $\tilde\phi$ on $X$, we obtain a cochain $\phi$ on $X/G$ whose value on a simplex $\sigma\subseteq X/G$ is given by $\tilde\phi(\tilde\sigma)$, where $\tilde\sigma\subseteq X$ is any lift of $\sigma$. Regularity ensures that these lifts all differ by an element of $G$, so that this is well-defined.

Hence under these (topologically quite mild) conditions your invariant cohomology $H^*(\mathcal{C}_G)$ is the orbit space cohomology $H^*(X/G)$. You can then interpret your homomorphism $H^*(\mathcal{C}_G)\to H^*_G(X;A)$ as being induced by the map $$X_G:=EG\times_G X\to X/G$$ which collapses $EG$ to a point. When the action is free, this is a (weak) homotopy equivalence, and so $H^*(\mathcal{C}_G)\to H^*_G(X;A)$ is an isomorphism. In general, this map can be analysed using the Leray spectral sequence (see Borel's "Seminar on transformation groups", for example).

If you are interested in $G=\mathbb{Z}/p$ or $G=S^1$, you should look up "Smith-Richardson theory".

Comment: "the invariant cochains on $X$ are the same thing as cochains on the orbit space X/G". That was what I originally thought, but I was confused by the following example. Let $X=\mathbb{R}^2$, and let $G = C_2$ act on $X$ by $x \mapsto -x$. We will work with $\mathbb{Z}/2$ coefficients. Then $H^2(\mathcal{C}_G) = \mathbb{Z}/2$ (the non-trivial class is the Poincare dual of the 0-chain which assigns 1 to the origin), whereas $X/G$ is still homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ so $H^2(X/G) = 0$.

Comment: Just to be clear, by "$x \mapsto -x$" I am referring to vector $x$, or in coordinate notation $(x,y) \mapsto (-x,-y)$

Comment: @Dominic: I don't see a way to triangulate the plane to make your action a $G$-simplicial complex, so I think it's excluded from my setup. Even so, I'm not a 100% confident with my answer. I'll think about it some more.

Comment: Doesn't a simple triangular tiling, with (0,0) at a vertex, work? Of course, then the problem seems to be that you can't represent the non-trivial G-invariant cochain as a G-invariant *simplicial* cochain... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_tiling

Comment: @Dominic: Looking back at your example, you seem to be assuming that Poincaré duality holds for invariant (co)homology, to get a non-trivial $H^2(\mathcal{C_G}$. This might need checking. Or maybe you can see an invariant $2$-cocycle in the triangulation?

Comment: "you seem to be assuming that Poincaré duality holds for invariant (co)homology". That is a good point, but I think this is not the main issue, as the following example demonstrates: $X = \mathbb{R}^2$, $G = C_3$ acts by $2\pi/3$ rotations, and $\mathbb{Z}/3$ coefficients. In that case we can choose a $G$-invariant triangulation which has the origin at the center of a face, in which case we easily see directly that $H^2(\mathcal{C}_G) = \mathbb{Z}/3$. The problem seems to be that this cohomology is not invariant under barycentric subdivision!

Comment: By the way the $X=\mathbb{R}^2$, $G = C_3$, $\mathbb{Z}/3$ coefficients example works in "invariant singular cohomology" too, without needing to refer to a triangulation. Define a singular 2-cochain which is assigns 1 to a simplex if and only if it contains the origin, otherwise 0. Then it's clear that this cochain is $G$-invariant, and moreover it cannot be written as the coboundary of a $G$-invariant 1-cochain because such a coboundary would always assign 0 to a G-invariant triangle surrounding the origin.

Comment: @Dominic: Regarding your comment one above, this triangulation certainly violates the 1st condition of regularity, which asks that for any $g\in G$ and simplex $s$, the intersection $s\cap g(s)$ is fixed pointwise by $g$. That's a good point though, $H^*(\mathcal{C}_G)$ seems to depend on the triangulation.

Comment: Regarding your last comment, I'm not convinced that what you describe is a singular $2$-cocycle. It would have to vanish on the boundary of any singular simplex $\sigma:\Delta^3\to \mathbb{R}^2$. What if I take $\sigma$ to be a composition $\Delta^3\to \Delta^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$, where first map is a simplicial collapse and the second encloses the origin in the interior of the triangle? It would seem your cochain take the value $2$ on such a simplex. (Sorry for being obstinate, it's not in my nature, honest! Probably we're both right, and the regularity condition is actually restricitive here.)

Comment: "I'm not convinced that what you describe is a singular 2-cocycle". You're right, of course, but I suppose that we can reinterpret this 2-cocycle as a simplicial cochain on the abstract simplicial complex containing all possible simplex embeddings into $X$ (where we assign $+/-1$ depending on the orientation)? That seems to be the most "fundamental" way to define invariant simplicial cohomology.

Answer (score 5):

If $G$ is a finite group acting by simplicial automorphisms on a simplicial complex $X$, then

$$H^{\ast}(X/G;\mathbb{Q}) = (H^{\ast}(X;\mathbb{Q}))^{G} = H^{\ast}((C^{\ast}(X;\mathbb{Q}))^G),$$

where the superscripts indicate that we are taking the invariants with respect to $G$.  For a proof, see Proposition 1.1 (and its proof) in my note "The action on homology of finite groups of automorphisms of surfaces and graphs", available on my webpage [here](http://www3.nd.edu/~andyp/notes/).  It is definitely necessary to take $\mathbb{Q}$ coefficients here (the referenced proof will make it clear why this is the case).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the case where the coefficients are a finite Abelian group is really the one I am interested in.

Comment: Note that Andy's Proposition 1.1 works with any coefficients, and asserts an equivalence of cochain complexes $\mathcal{C}^*(X/G)\cong(\mathcal{C}^*(X))^G$, as in my answer. So the outer terms are always equal. Only in Lemma 1.2 are rational coefficients used, to get equality with the middle term. This depends on having a suitable triangulation, of course (so that simplices of $X/G$ correspond to orbits of simplices in $X$).