# Cohomology of the amplitude space of unlabeled quantum networks

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, fibration

I am investigating a particular map from a product of three-spheres to the moduli space of (non-negative, real edge weight) networks. The map in question is

$$f: \smash{\left( \mathbb{S}^3 \right)}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}^N$$

where $N=\binom{n}{2}$ is the number of edges of a complete graph. We are placing a qubit on each edge of the underlying graph, given by $g: \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}^N \rightarrow \{0,1\}^N$, a semi-ring morphism.

A qubit lives in the Bloch sphere, $\mathbb{S}^3$.  Define $e_{ij}:=e_{ij}^0 \lvert0\rangle + e_{ij}^1 \rvert1\rangle$, with $\lvert e_{ij}^0\rvert^2 + \lvert e_{ij}^1\rvert^2 = 1$, and $e_{ij}^k \in \mathbb{C}$. $f$ is given by applying $e_{ij} \rightarrow \lvert e_{ij}^1\rvert^2$ for $1 \le i < j \le n$.

To get unlabeled networks, quotient by the permutation group $\Sigma_n$ where $\sigma \cdot e_{ij} = e_{\sigma(i)\sigma(j)}$.

Let $Y_n=(\mathbb{S}^3)^N / \Sigma_n$ and $X_N=(\mathbb{S}^3)^N/\Sigma_N$. What is $H^*(Y_n;\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: The fiber over a generic point is a product of tori, while over a point with some of the coordinates $1$ (or $0$) the corresponding tori are replaced with circles, so it is not a fibration. I think.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Thanks. I need to write this down but the fibers should be pretty obvious. The quotient space is an orbifold and the fundamental domain looks like a convex polyhedral region with many facets/strata of varying dimension, some of which are glued together.

Comment: You might benefit from looking at the $\Sigma_n$-equivariant cohomology of $(\mathbf S^3)^N$ - see Ken Brown's "Cohomology of groups", VII.7 and exercises therein

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Thanks for the reference, I'll take a look.

Comment: ChatGPT is not computing anything.  E.g. $Y_n$ is connected so $H^0(Y_n) = \mathbb Z$.

Comment: @PhilTosteson Right, my collaborator is really embarrassing themselves here. Perhaps "claims" instead of "computes". I'll talk to them and revise.

Comment: Let’s be clear. ChatGPT does not, and cannot, “compute” anything at all. That’s not what it does.

Comment: @HJRW Well, ChatGPT predicts the probabilities of next words given a window of previous words or tokens. We do something quite similar when we write down one math symbol after the next.

Comment: @JacksonWalters The process by which I would write a paragraph like your ChatGPT examples is in fact substantially different from the process that I use to write a normal sentence (such as this one).  If I followed the process of simply writing down the most likely next token, then with high probability my statements would be false.

Comment: @PhilTosteson I'm on board with the idea that ChatGPT is with high likelihood wrong, though it is writing clearly. The processes are, course, different. I have argued elsewhere that the language output of a human brain is influenced by many factors. Math knowledge is high level abstract conceptual data which is organized in a certain way, which we are projecting down to vector and text data that is serially read out. We also have lots of videos and images in mind that are being projected down to language. It's like ChatGPT took a bunch of notes but never did any of the homework.

Comment: @JacksonWalters I asked ChatGPT to compute the integral homology groups of the free group $F_2$. For $n=0, 1, 2, 3$ it gave me $\mathbf{Z}, \mathbf{Z}^2, \mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}, \mathbf{Z}$, and for $n=4$ it gave me $S_3$ (!). It's total nonsense. Saying that it is "with high likelihood wrong" is a massive understatement. The fact that ChatGPT is "writing clearly" is not a redeeming factor by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: Today I also learnt from ChatGPT that "$H_8(F_2; \mathbf{Z}) \cong \zeta(3)$ (the Riemann zeta function at 3). This is the exceptional group, and it's a nontrivial result in homotopy theory related to the so-called 'Kummer congruences.' It's a manifestation of a more complex and less straightforward structure in the homology." How's that for clear writing?

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda That's a good example. I imagine there are a lot of instances where ChatGPT is flat out wrong. How would you phrase it? High likelihood of wrong is about as diplomatic as I can be. It's right sometimes, too. I mean, sure, being eloquent isn't a redeeming quality if you're lying or inciting violence or whatever, but this is a little more benign. Its guide to computing the groups is fine.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda I'm going to update the answer and remove ChatGPT, and its cool that you know how to compute that difficult-to-compute group, but can we focus on at least computing $H^*((S^3)^N / \Sigma_N)$ at least? The only entity in the building brave enough to answer has been ChatGPT (and Siu-Cheong) so far.

Comment: @PhilTosteson Thanks. I suppose I don't understand why it's independent of $n$. So $H(X_N,\mathbb{Q}) \cong H(S^3,\mathbb{Q})$? It makes sense that computing over $\mathbb{Q}$ would kill torsion. I recall thinking about this and noting that the representation theory of $\Sigma_n$ is found by considering its action on the second symmetric power of the standard representation, so $(2,n-2)$ in the language of Specht modules and Young diagrams, and is irreducible. "Cohomology of symmetric products" by Minoru Nakaoka (1957) seems relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[$H^*(Y_n;\mathbb{Q}) \cong (H^*((S^3)^N;\mathbb{Q}))^{\Sigma_n}$](https://mathoverflow.net/a/263661/1345).

Hence with rational coefficients this reduces to analyzing the invariant subspace of the action of $\Sigma_n$ on $H^*((S^3)^N;\mathbb{Q})\cong (\mathbb{Q}^2)^{\otimes N}$.

Let $H^*(S^3;\mathbb{Q})$ be generated by $s^0 \in H^0(S^3)$  and $s^3\in H^3(S^3)$.
We have a projection $p_i: (S^3)^N \to S^3$ to the $i$th factor.
Then $H^*((S^3)^N)$ has a basis $p_1^*(s^{i_1})\cup \cdots \cup p_N^*(s^{i_N})$, where $i_j\in \{0,3\}$. We may identify $H^*((S^3)^N)$ with $H^*(S^3)^{\otimes N}$ via the Kunneth formula with basis $s^{i_1}\otimes\cdots\otimes s^{i_N}$ (note that this is a graded commutative tensor product of [graded commutative algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded-commutative_ring?wprov=sfti1)).

For a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and a finite group $G$ acting on $V$, we have a retract $av: V\to V^G$ (the fixed points of the $G$-action on $V$) given by $av(v)=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G} g(v)$. Hence for any basis of $V$, the image under $av$ will span $V^G$.

Let’s apply this to the $\Sigma_N$ action on $H^*((S^3)^N)\cong H^3(S^3)^{\otimes N}$. For $\sigma \in \Sigma_N$, suppose that $(i_1,\ldots, i_N)=(i_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,i_{\sigma(N)})$. Consider the subset $J=\{ j | i_j=3\}$, then $\sigma$ restricts to a permutation of this set. Let $\epsilon_J(\sigma)$ be the sign of $\sigma_{|J}$. Then $\sigma (s^{i_1}\otimes \cdots\otimes s^{i_N})= s^{i_{\sigma(1)}}\otimes\cdots\otimes s^{i_{\sigma(N)}} = \epsilon_J(\sigma)   s^{i_1}\otimes \cdots\otimes s^{i_N}$ due to the rule for changing signs of permutations of graded commutative tensor products.
Thus we see that $av(s^{i_1}\otimes \cdots \otimes s^{i_N})$ (with associated $J=\{j|i_j=3\}$) will $= 0$ if there is $\sigma\in \Sigma_N$ such that $\sigma(J)=J$ and $\epsilon_J(\sigma)=-1$, and otherwise will $= \frac{1}{N!} \sum_{\sigma\in\Sigma_N} s^{i_{\sigma(1)}}\otimes \cdots \otimes s^{i_{\sigma(N)}} \neq 0$.

Now lets apply this to $H^*(Y_n;\mathbb{Q})\cong H^*((S^3)^N;\mathbb{Q})^{\Sigma_n} \cong (H^*(S^3)^{\otimes N})^{\Sigma_n}$, $N=\binom{n}{2}$.

We get a generating set for $H^*((S^3)^N)$ corresponding to subgraphs of the complete graph $K_n$ on $n$ vertices where if an edge does not connect $i,j$ we choose the generator $s^0$ of $H^0(S^3)$ corresponding to the $ij$ factor and if an edge connects $i,j$, we choose the generator $s^3$ of $H^3(S^3)$. Then $\Sigma_n$ acts on the vertices and hence on the edges. For a generator corresponding to the graph $\Gamma$, and a permuation $\sigma\in \Sigma_n$ preserving $\Gamma$, we may consider the sign of the action of $\Sigma_n$ on $E(\Gamma)$. If this sign is trivial for all $\sigma\in Aut(\Gamma) < \Sigma_n$, then the averaging operator on the corresponding generator will be non-zero, and we get an element of $H^*((S^3)^N)^{\Sigma_n}-\{0\}$. If the sign is non-trivial, then the averaging operator will be zero. One may also see that the elements will be linearly independent for each isomorphism type of graph, since the corresponding tensor factors will be distinct.

Thus the dimension of the fixed subspace, and hence $H^*(Y_n;\mathbb{Q})$, will be the number of isomorphism classes of simple graphs $\Gamma$ on $n$ vertices such that the sign of the automorphism group $Aut(\Gamma)$ acting on $E(\Gamma)$ is trivial.

Comment: This is a beautiful answer, thank you.

Comment: @JacksonWalters: a couple of comments: 1. It might be helpful to edit the question to clarify what is being asked. It  is confusing since it was edited several times. It took me a couple of reads and looking at the comments to understand what you were asking. 2. I assumed coefficients Q which works essentially because the transfer map is inverse to pullback on the invariant sub space. With positive characteristic coefficients the answer may be more complicated.

Comment: 1) I'll edit the question to clarify what is being asked, which was "what is $H^*((S^3)^N/\Sigma_n;\mathbb{Z})$?". It was confusing because the question evolved from studying "properties" of the fibration to simply asking for the cohomology. 2) $\mathbb{Q}$ coefficients are fine if it simplifies the computation significantly, which it does here. Perhaps the torsion is interesting, I don't know.