# What is $H^*(\mathbb{CP}^{2^N-1}/\Sigma_n;\mathbb{Z})$ when $N=\binom{n}{2}$?

Tags: graph-theory, finite-groups, cohomology, quantum-mechanics, equivariant-cohomology

$H^*((S^3)^N/\Sigma_n;\mathbb{Q})$ is computed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/453878/15133).

It makes a little more sense to compute $H^*((S^2)^N/\Sigma_n;\mathbb{Q})$ given that [global phase is irrelevant](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/34216/26436). The proof is exactly the same.

---

Still, that's not really the input space for quantum graphs. It makes more sense to use $N=\binom{n}{2}$ and $P(V^{\otimes N}) \cong \mathbb{CP}^{2^N-1}$ where $V \cong \mathbb{C}^2$.

Define an action of $\Sigma_n$ on $P(V^{\otimes N})$ as follows. Let $e_{12}, \ldots e_{n-1,n}$ be a basis for each $V$ such that $e_{ij}=e_{ij}^0|0\rangle+e_{ij}^1|1\rangle$ where $e_{ij}^k \in \mathbb{C}$. Then a basis for $V^{\otimes N}$ is given by $e_{12}^{k_{12}} \otimes \ldots \otimes e_{n-1,n}^{k_{n-1,n}}$ where $k_{ij} \in \{0,1\}$. $\sigma \cdot e_{12}^{k_{12}} \otimes \ldots \otimes e_{n-1,n}^{k_{n-1,n}} = e_{\sigma(1)\sigma(2)}^{k_{12}} \otimes \ldots \otimes e_{\sigma(n-1)\sigma(n)}^{k_{n-1,n}}$. We can act on $P(V^{\otimes N})$ by using projective coordinates $\sigma \cdot \left[ x_1, \ldots , x_{2^N}\right] = \left[ \sigma(x_1), \ldots, \sigma(x_{2^N})\right]$.

$H^*(\mathbb{CP}^{2^N-1}/\Sigma_n;\mathbb{Z}) = H^*(\mathbb{CP}^{2^N-1};\mathbb{Z})^{\Sigma_n}$. How do I compute this or adapt the proof linked above?

Comment: The symmetric group acts trivially on the cohomology of $\mathbb{CP}^{2^N-1}$, as does the entire (projective linear group) of biholomorphisms of the projective space.  So the entire cohomology ring is invariant.

Comment: @JasonStarr Okay, that answers that. Is it obvious why that's true?

Comment: This action comes from a linear action on $V^{\otimes N}$ and so it factors through the action of the general linear group $GL(V^{\otimes N})$, which is path-connected, so every element acts trivially on any homotopy invariant.

Comment: What @QiaochuYuan said :)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you, that’s clear. Thanks Jason as well.