# Cohomology of finite symmetric products of manifolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, manifolds, homology

Let $M$ be a closed, orientable manifold of dimension $k$. I am looking for results to determine explicitly the (co)homology groups and/or cohomology ring structure (in integer or rational coefficients) of the $n$-fold symmetric product of $M$, denoted by $SP^n(M)$ for arbitrary $n$. In particular, I'm interested in cases when $M$ is a finite product of spheres, or a finite product of projective spaces. IG MacDonald has a result for $k = 2$ (surfaces) but I am interested in case of arbitrary $k$.

One way to approach this is to understand the topological structure of $SP^n(M)$ and then use it to compute $H^i \left(SP^n(M)\right)$ for various $i$, while the other is to directly get results on the (co)homology groups of $SP^n(M)$ in terms of that of $M$. Either way, I have not been successful in finding suitable references in the literature. I have found some partial results on $H^i \left(SP^n\left(S^{k}\right)\right)$ for small values of $n$ in Nakaoka's work, but nothing in general for "nice" manifolds $M$, even for the $k-$torus $T^{k} = S^{1} \times S^{1} \times \cdots \times S^{1}$, product done $k-$times for $k>2$.

I also know that DV Gugnin has a result on the functoriality of the cohomology of symmetric products with integer coefficients but the result is purely theoretical and not helpful for my purpose of determining explicitly the ring structure of $H^*\left(SP^n(M)\right)$. I’m looking for more information about either the space $SP^n(M)$ or the (co)homology of $SP^n(M)$ for arbitrary $n$ so that I can find explicitly the cohomology ring $H^*\left(SP^n(M)\right)$.

Any help or references would be appreciated.

PS: A related question was posted here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4776534/cohomology-ring-of-symmetric-products-of-manifolds and answered only for $k=2$. My current question here focuses only on $k > 2$.

Comment: This was asked on MSE yesterday - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4776534/cohomology-ring-of-symmetric-products-of-manifolds - this kind of crossposting is not appropriate

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko the linked question was answered only for $k = 2$ (surfaces). This is a reformulated question specifically for manifolds of higher dimensions with more information about known results included, like Nakaoka's result.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16288/asking-the-same-question-on-mse-and-mo

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455469/cohomology-of-finite-symmetric-products-of-manifolds#comment1179220_455469), why not move your description of the difference between the two questions into the question itself, at which point it will be convenient also to link there to the cross-posted question?

Comment: It is much easier to compute motivic invariants of the symmetric products (like the Euler characteristic) if that's of interest. See for eg. https://people.math.wisc.edu/~lmaxim/sym_lib60.pdf and the papers they cite and are cited by.

Comment: @Asvin thank you for this reference. I did see this paper and there's also a paper: https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969720 giving explicit formula for Betty numbers for $SP^2(K)$ for triangulable complex $K$, though it tells little about the cohomology. Another paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0408417 gives a generating function for the Euler characteristic but that is even less helpful for my purpose.

Answer (score 8):

[$H^*(SP^n(M);\mathbb{Q}) \cong (H^*((M)^n;\mathbb{Q}))^{\Sigma_n} \cong (H^*(M;\mathbb{Q})^{\otimes n})^{\Sigma_n}$](https://mathoverflow.net/a/263661/1345)

Note that the tensor product here (via the Kunneth formula) is a graded tensor product of rings. At least this result reduces the cohomology computation to an algebraic question depending only on the ring structure of $H^*(M; \mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just to clarify, does $\left(H^*((M)^n, \mathbb{Q})\right)^{\Sigma_{n}}$ mean the quotient ring $H^*((M)^n, \mathbb{Q})/ \Sigma_{n}$ where $\Sigma_{n}$ is the $n-$th symmetric group, or does it mean ring homomorphisms from $\Sigma_{n}$ to $H^*((M)^n, \mathbb{Q})$?

Comment: @JE2912 Neither of these quite makes sense. The first (if you mean setting $x ~ \sigma(x)$ for all permutations) is no longer a vector space, or even a group. You could refer to coinvariants, denoted $V_{Sigma_n}$, where you quotient by the subspace generated by all vectors $x - \sigma(x)$. The second is not meaningful because $\Sigma_n$ is not a ring. What you want is the set of fixed points: $V^{Sigma_n}$ denotes the set of vectors with $\sigma(x) = x$ for all $x$.

Comment: Yes, it’s the fixed points, the notation is explained in the link.

Comment: @mme you mean $V^{\Sigma_{n}} = \{x \in V: \sigma(x) = x \forall \sigma \in \Sigma_{n}\}$?

Comment: @JE2912  ${}$